# Trying to create custom << operator c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a custom `<<` operator, but my compiler aways throws this error: `invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char *')`.

Here is my code:

```
inline std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &stream, String &string) {
    return stream << string.toCharArray();
}
```

Here is my `String` class:

```
class String {
private:
    char *content;
    int size;

    void init();
public:
    String();
    String(const char *content);
    ~String();

    const char *toCharArray();

    String operator + (String append);
    String operator + (const char *append);
    void append(const char *string);
};

inline std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &stream, String &string) {
    return stream << string.toCharArray();
}
```

Test example:

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    String *test = new String("test");

    cout << *test << endl;

    cout << (*test  + "bb").toCharArray() << endl;

    delete test;

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code as-is looks fine (except you should take `const String&` in `operator<<`... but that wouldn't cause the error).

Comment: @Barry done. I put my entire `String` class.

Comment: No, not done. What is the `String` you are constructing? Where are you trying to stream it?

Comment: @Barry I'm trying to stream to `stdout`.

Comment: In the code. Where *in the code*. Please reread the link I posted. The example should be complete and verifiable. Yours is neither.

Comment: Tip: C++ has delegating constructors now, so you can probably refactor away the `.init()`. Any reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: Using the answer given, the program compiles, but when I try to use `cout << someString << endl;`, it prints a reference `0x7fe549c04c80`.

Comment: Are you sure your string doesn't actually contain that?

Comment: @brewbuck no. If I use `cout << someString.toCharArray() << endl` it outputs `test`

Comment: Do you have any other custom operator<<() in play?

Comment: @brewbuck no, this is the only operator <<() that I'm using.

Comment: @brewbuck damn, it's obvious why it's printing the reference. But when I try to use `cout << *test << endl`, it throws a seg fault

Comment: The code you posted isn't complete enough to compile, but I made some reasonable changes to make it compile, and it's working for me. Can you possibly condense this to a single block of code that is compilable on its own which demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @brewbuck Thanks for your help, I managed to make it work. I needed to include `iostream` to avoid the Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your operator<<() takes the string argument as a non-const reference, the object you pass must be an l-value. But it isn't. You are trying to pass a string literal, which (presumably) will be converted to a temporary instance of String, but temporaries can't be l-values.

If you change the String reference parameter to a const reference, it should work.

Comment: When I use `String` as const reference, it throws this error: `error: member function 'toCharArray' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const String', but function is not marked const`

Comment: You'll need to make toCharArray() a const function. It ought to be anyway.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Change it to `const char *toCharArray() const;`.

Comment: @brewbuck it worked! Could you explain why it works? I'm new to C++, so I don't know exactly what `const` after the function declaration means.

Comment: @brewbuck it compiled, but it streams a reference, not the content.